How does one add a sub bar to an interaction control on an ol-ext EditBar?
I would like to add a sub bar to the native 'Point' and 'LineString' interaction controls on an Openlayers ol-ext EditBar. The purpose is to set a subType variable for the parent interactions. The subType is used to apply a conditional style. ie interaction='DrawPoint' subType='Purple Hexagon'.
Currently I am using an external radio button group to set the subType but I would like the UX to be consistent. I can disable the DrawPoint interaction on the EditBar and then add my own Toggle Draw interaction with my custom sub bar. However, this messes up the order of the EditBar icons.
I would prefer to add the sub bar to the native EditBar interaction control but have been successful in doing so.
EditBar API docs

Show is a custom 'Point' interaction control with a submenu on the main control bar, added after the EditBar. I would like the native EditBar 'Point' control (to the right of select control) to have this submenu.
